# Why do some fields care so much more about citation styles?

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

On this website, there are 120 questions tagged [citation-style](/questions/tagged/citation-style), and probably many more without the tag (a search for APA returns 244 results).

I work in applied mathematics, and among my colleagues the general approach to citation styles varies between "it doesn't matter as long as it's consistent" and "I use Bibtex and that's it; frankly I don't even know how this style is called".

**Why is citation style considered important** in other fields and receives so much interest? What is it that I am missing?

Comment: You clearly have never had an article administratively rejected based on incorrect citations.

Comment: @StrongBad, but, I think,  "why do journals, confereces, or other publication venues *really* care?" is the real question.

Comment: Many of the questions with this tag are about broader academic writing issues than the actual citation style, and most of the questions with this tag have few upvotes and few answers.  I wouldn't say that the readership considers this to be a particularly important topic.

Comment: I think many of the people who ask questions in this tag are students who are being asked to use formal citations for the first time, often for a paper in their coursework or something. Not experienced academics.

Comment: @ff524 Then the question is why their teachers have an inexplicable obsession with citation styles and demand a specific one in their assignments.

Comment: You can ask the same question for clothing styles. No big deal to you and many of us. But big deal to some. As for the students asking about styles, if you're inexperienced, it may not be too surprising if you get worried about really minor stuff simply because you don't know it doesn't matter to many.

Comment: This is also why automated styling systems which are good at obeying the rules (BibTeX, EndNote, etc.) are popular. You put the cite in a location, and it formats the in-text or footnote portion, and it formats the bibliography or endnote portion.

Comment: When I started writing my first academic text (master thesis), my advisor e-mailed me a bibtex stylesheet and told me how to use it, and that was that.

Comment: @StrongBad I don't even know anyone (in real life) that has ever had an article rejected based on incorrect citations.  That would be utterly unthinkable in my field.

Comment: @JeffE happens all the time in my field. If the citations style is wrong, or if the figures are not at the end with the captions in a table of figures, or if you deviate from the instructions in any number of ways.  It is generally not a big deal, the "rejection" comes within 24 hours (usually) and you just fix it.

Comment: It's not really a rejection if you can just fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of a citation style is to provide the reader with references in a standard and legible way. Using a certain style within a research field makes reading and skimming through citations within the field's publications more efficient.

Uniform citation style within a unit of certain field makes the unit's publications look uniform and adds to the quality of the publication, just as good grammar and otherwise good appearance does.

Arguably, a big fuss is when students are learning the correct ways of citation.

Answer (score 0):

There are styles because otherwise it would be a complete mess. I speculate that it has to do with the way archiving and indexing of publications are done in a given library/institution/society, and the type of publications in the field (peer-reviewed articles vs book chapters): in some fields you may retrieve a publication with Journal + Volume + Page, whereas in other ones, you need Authors + Title +  Year + Publisher. So different needs, different styles.

Comment: I don't think it's field-specific, but it is related to the type of the publication that you wish to cite: to identify an *article*, you need journal+volume+page, and to identify a *book*, you need title+year+publisher.